# Azure keyvault client 1.0.0 initiate client

Tags: java, azure, sdk, azure-keyvault

In azure Keyvault website [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/keyvault)

I found this code:

```
KeyVaultClient kvc = new KeyVaultClient(credentials);
KeyBundle returnedKeyBundle = getKey(vaultUrl, keyName);
JsonWebKey jsonKey = returnedKeyBundle.key();
```

But how to get he client credentials is not explained, and all the old methods is not valid with the library version 1.0.0.
I want to use application id and secret to authenticate, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, I think the code below is that you want if you had known how to register an application in Azure AD.

```
String clientId = "<client id of your application registed on Azure AD>";
String domain = "<your talnet id>";
String secret = "<client key of your application registed on Azure AD>";
String subscription = "<your subscription id>";
AzureTokenCredentials cred = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId, domain, secret, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
KeyVaultClient kvc = new KeyVaultClient(credentials);
```

Or follow the figure below to register an application in Azure AD on Azure portal, then to do the above.

[image]

---

Update: Please add the `azure` dependency as below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: in azure 1.0.0 ApplicationTokenCredentials does not exist anymore

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-keyvault</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: @JackLebbos I updated my reply, please add the `azure` dependency.

Comment: thanks it worked but now I cannot access keyvault com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.models.KeyVaultErrorException status 401 when trying to get key