# Access denied linking variable group to key vault in VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-devops, permission-denied, access-denied, azure-keyvault

When I try to link a variable group to key vault in VSTS, every time I select my endpoint, it tells me:

*"Specified Azure endpoint needs to have "Get, List" secret management permissions on the selected key vault. Click "Authorize" to enable VSTS to set these permissions or manage secret permissions in Azure portal."*

It makes no sense. That specific endpoint has Get and List for secrets, keys, certificates. The endpoint is using the correct Service Principal Client ID- I know because I pulled its corresponding app registration up in Azure by searching with that ID. And the app registration is specifically listed in the key vault's Access policies, with the correct permissions.

Trying to click "Authorize" in VSTS just give me

*"Resource not found for the segment 'DirectoryDataService.getServicePrincipalsByAppIds'. For troubleshooting refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=835898"*

and the endpoint is broken until I re-verify it.

I'm kind of at my wit's end here- everything is set exactly as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/variable-groups?view=vsts says it should be.

**Edit:** Turns out the Azure tried to add the app reg as a person instead of an app when I listed it in the ARM template by object ID (app ID *most definitely* does not work there). So now I just need to figure out how to add it as an application in the ARM template...

**Edit Edit:** Soooo... the Object ID the Azure Portal shows for an App Registration? That's not the Object ID the ARM template wants. It wants the... I'm not sure what you'd call it. In Powershell, you use it with -Object ID, but when you list the properties, it's under "Id". Whatever. To get it, you run

```
Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -SearchString "[your-app-reg-name]"
```

And it shows up under **Id**. That's what you want to use as an object ID in your ARM template.

Comment: Ah, sorry, no, the problem was finding the right ID for the app reg, since it's not the Application ID. Thank you for the information, though!

Comment: Glad to hear the issue fixed, you could share your solution here and add a reply with more details, then mark your own reply as an answer, which will also help others in the community.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error `Resource not found for the segment 'DirectoryDataService.getServicePrincipalsByAppIds`, the issue seems more related to Azure side.

To access azure-keyvault you need four things :

```
 - clientId = "<client id of your application registed on Azure AD>";
 - domain = "<your talnet id>";
 - secret = "<client key of your application registed on Azure AD>";
 - subscription = "<your subscription id>";
```

Then these will combine ApplicationTokenCredentials, finally Authorize to KeyVaultClient . Suggest you take a look at this question: [Azure keyvault client 1.0.0 initiate client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44874449/azure-keyvault-client-1-0-0-initiate-client/44878729#44878729)

[image]

Besides also double check/confirm the specific endpoint has Get and List for secrets, keys, certificates.